# List comprehension to extract a list of tuples from dictionary

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, tuples

I'd like to use list comprehension on the following list;

```
movie_dicts = [{'title':'A Boy and His Dog', 'year':1975, 'rating':6.6},
           {'title':'Ran', 'year':1985, 'rating': 8.3},
           {'title':'True Grit', 'year':2010, 'rating':8.0},
           {'title':'Scanners', 'year':1981, 'rating': 6.7}]
```

using my knowledge of list comprehension and dictionaries, I know that

```
movie_titles = [x['title'] for x in movie_dicts]
print movie_titles
```

will print a list with movie titles.

In order to extracts a list of (title, year) tuples I've tried -

```
movie_tuples = [x for ('title','year') in movie_dicts]
print movie_tuples
```

and I receive the error SyntaxError: can't assign to literal

I'm unsure on how to fetch the two (specific) key/value pairs using list comprehension (doing so would generate a tuple automatically?)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
movie_dicts = [
    {'title':'A Boy and His Dog', 'year':1975, 'rating':6.6},
    {'title':'Ran', 'year':1985, 'rating': 8.3},
    {'title':'True Grit', 'year':2010, 'rating':8.0},
    {'title':'Scanners', 'year':1981, 'rating': 6.7}
]

title_year = [(i['title'],i['year']) for i in movie_dicts]
```

gives

```
[('A Boy and His Dog', 1975),
 ('Ran', 1985),
 ('True Grit', 2010),
 ('Scanners', 1981)]
```

OR

```
import operator
fields = operator.itemgetter('title','year')
title_year = [fields(i) for i in movie_dicts]
```

which gives exactly the same result.

Comment: Actually the brackets *are* necessary inside LCs :P You can leave them out in assignments, return, yield statements (pretty much everywhere else, those are all i can think of right now).

Comment: If you are using itemgetter, you can also just use `map(fields, movie_dict)` instead of the LC

Answer (score 3):

This version has a minimum of repeating yourself:

```
>>> fields = "title year".split()
>>> movie_tuples = [tuple(map(d.get,fields)) for d in movie_dicts]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[(movie_dict['title'], movie_dict['year']) for movie_dict in movie_dicts]
```

Remember, `xs = [expr for target in expr2]` is equivalent (almost - ignoring `StopIteration` for simplicity) to:

```
xs = []
for target in expr2:
    xs.append(expr)
```

So `target` needs to be a plain old variable name or some tuple to unpack to. But since `movie_dicts` doesn't contain sequences to unpack from but simple single values (dicts), you must limit it to one variable. Then when you append to the list being generated, you can create a tuple and do whatever else you want to do with the current item.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use a list comprehension, you could always do:

```
list(d.iteritems())
```